# How to check if vim version 8.1+ is installed

Tags: bash, shell, vim

I have the following attempt at a vim script to check to see if it is installed and if its version is recent (8+):

```
# Check if we have vim version 8.1+ installed
VIM_PATH=$(which vim)
VIM_VERSION=$(vim --version |grep '8.[123]')
if [ -z "$VIM_PATH" || -z "$VIM_VERSION" ]
then
   ...
fi
```

Is the above a valid script? What might be a better way to grab the version and check if

Comment: `if grep -q 8.[1-9] < <(vim -h | head -n1); then ...` version greater than  or equal to 8.1 found.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin until vim 9 :)

Comment: Yep, then an either/or would be needed, or better, a `case` statement `:)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since `vim --version` isn't very machine-readable, I would be tempted to try

```
if vim --cmd 'if v:version >= 801 | q | else | cq | fi' ; then
    # vim at least 8.1
fi
```

which uses a snippet of vim script to do the comparison. `--cmd` runs a command before opening any files or running `.vimrc`; the `cq` command exits with an error status, and `q` exits with a success status (necessary because otherwise vim would want to edit a blank file!). `|` allows placing multiple vim commands on a single line, like `;` in shell.

Comment: in the case that vim isn't installed, what would happen in the above case?

Comment: @David542 the if condition would fail, since `vim` can't be run. However, you can still do a separate check if yo want a quieter failure, or you want to distinguish "old vim" from "no vim".